# The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture: No Scaffold widget found

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, bottom-sheet, scaffold

I am trying to implement *showBottomSheet* after *onPressed* on an **ElevatedButton** but i am getting below error

```
======== Exception caught by gesture ===============================================================
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
No Scaffold widget found.

BottomSheetScrollSheet widgets require a Scaffold widget ancestor.
The specific widget that could not find a Scaffold ancestor was: BottomSheetScrollSheet
  state: _BottomSheetScrollSheetState#f9b53
The ancestors of this widget were: 
  : Builder
  : MaterialApp
    state: _MaterialAppState#fe76c
  : MyApp
  ...

Typically, the Scaffold widget is introduced by the MaterialApp or WidgetsApp widget at the top of your application widget tree.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      debugCheckHasScaffold.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/debug.dart:118:7)
#1      debugCheckHasScaffold (package:flutter/src/material/debug.dart:129:4)
#2      showBottomSheet (package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart:770:10)
#3      _BottomSheetScrollSheetState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:master_learn/screens/bottomsheet_scrollsheet.dart:82:27)
#4      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:989:21)
#5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:198:24)
#6      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:608:11)
#7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:296:5)
#8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:230:7)
#9      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:563:9)
#10     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:94:12)
#11     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:139:9)
#12     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:539:8)
#13     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:137:18)
#14     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:123:7)
#15     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:439:19)
#16     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:419:22)
#17     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:322:11)
#18     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:374:7)
#19     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:5)
#20     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:296:7)
#21     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:279:7)
#25     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:170:10)
#26     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:331:7)
#27     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:94:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#ece38
  debugOwner: GestureDetector
  state: possible
  won arena
  finalPosition: Offset(166.0, 192.3)
  finalLocalPosition: Offset(71.0, 28.3)
  button: 1
  sent tap down
====================================================================================================
```

Below is how i have implemented my code

```
 Center(
                child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5),
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          showBottomSheet(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (context) {
                                return Wrap(
                                  children: [
                                    ListTile(
                                      leading: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                                      title: Text("Title 1"),
                                    ),
                                    // Add keyboard padding
                                    Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                      bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom
                                    ))
                                  ],
                                );
                              });
                        },
                        child: const Text("Persistent Bottom Sheet"))))
```

When i am using `showModalBottomSheet` it is just working fine the problem starts when i am using `showBottomSheet`. I have tried to put the whole `showBottomSheet` in a void method and parsing context as parameters but its still giving me `The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture: No Scaffold widget found.` error.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you. I tried other way.

Create your BottomSheet method:

```
openBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
    return showBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return Wrap(
          children: [
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
              title: Text("Title 1"),
            ),
            // Add keyboard padding
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Your Widget

```
 ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          openBottomSheet(context);
          print('Bottom Sheet Open');
        },
        child: const Text("Persistent Bottom Sheet"),
      ),
```

For More Refer [`showBottomSheet`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ScaffoldState/showBottomSheet.html)

Comment: Ravindra S. Patil, its still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
Center(
                child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5),
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          scaffoldKey.currentState!.
                showBottomSheet((context) {
                                return Wrap(
                                  children: [
                                    ListTile(
                                      leading: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                                      title: Text("Title 1"),
                                    ),
                                    // Add keyboard padding
                                    Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                      bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom
                                    ))
                                  ],
                                );
                              });
                        },
                        child: const Text("Persistent Bottom Sheet"))))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was you wrote "showBottomSheet" instead of "showModalBottomSheet".

View output: [View](https://i.postimg.cc/25wjjYFz/Simulator-Screen-Shot-i-Phone-SE-3rd-generation-2023-08-30-at-13-19-51.png)

Source code:

```
Center(
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    await showModalBottomSheet(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return Wrap(
                          children: [
                            const ListTile(
                              leading: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                              title: Text("Title 1"),
                            ),
                            // Add keyboard padding
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                bottom:
                                    MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  },
                  child: const Text("Persistent Bottom Sheet"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a **showModalBottomSheet** instead of **showBottomSheet** and add parameter :`isScrollControlled: true.`

```
showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      builder://
);
```